# Нужна помощь по работе с картой

Tags: php, геолокация, карты

В базе имеются точки с указанием их долготы и широты в десятичных долях градуса, т.е. например: 53.20498753072359,49.96120754474532.

Разрабатывается импорт новых точек из csv. Есть условие новая точка не должна быть ближе 150м к уже существующей.

Функция рассчёта расстояния между двумя точками есть, но с учётом большого количества точек(например сейчас 1000 уже есть, нужно импортировать ещё 5000) перебирать для каждой новой точки расстояние до каждой существующей очень трудоёмко. Появилась идея оптимизации, для начала вытащить из базы все точки, которые попадают в квадрат стороной 300м и центром в новой добавляемой. И уже среди них перебирать расстояния(в большинстве случаев такого фильтра и погрешности будет достаточно.
Собственно вопрос: как определить угловые точки этого квадрата? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

"**Прямая геодезическая задача**"
Угол 45 градусов, расстояние 75 м

Вот здесь есть на C
[http://wiki.gis-lab.ru/w/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5:*%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F*%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0](http://wiki.gis-lab.ru/w/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.